# openmp for loop is not parallelized

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I'm trying to measure the running time of the parallel version and the serial one.

I have such a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/times.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 1024 * 20

long time_delta = 0;

struct rusage rusage_start;
struct rusage rusage_finish;

void bubble_sort(unsigned int* array) {
    unsigned int tmp = 0;
    bool no_swap = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = ARRAY_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        no_swap = 1;
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
                {
                    tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = tmp;
                    no_swap = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (no_swap)
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned int* array = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
    if(!array) { return -1; }
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        array[i] = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage_start);
    
    //sort
    bubble_sort(array);

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage_finish);
    time_delta = (1000000 * (rusage_finish.ru_utime.tv_sec - rusage_start.ru_utime.tv_sec)) + (rusage_finish.ru_utime.tv_usec - rusage_start.ru_utime.tv_usec);
    printf("Time: %li microseconds\n", time_delta);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and measure time like this:

```
gcc -openmp main.c -o prog && for n in {1..10}; do ./prog; done
```

The problem is that, if I change the number of threads in the function before for or remove the directive altogether, nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Everything seems to be correct. (I run the code on a VM with 4 cores; lscpu sees them.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop cannot (or *should not*) be parallelized because a variable declared outside its scope (`tmp`) is modified inside. In your case, this *particular* issue can be fixed by removing the current declaration you have for `tmp` and placing it inside the `if` block:

```c
    if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
    {
        unsigned int tmp = array[j]; // Now a LOCAL variable (one for each loop).
        array[j] = array[j + 1];
        array[j + 1] = tmp;
        no_swap = 0;
    }
```

In your code as it stands, there is a (high) possibility of data races if loops executing in parallel try to simultaneously read or write the *single* `tmp` variable.

However, you also have a similar problem with the `no_swap` variable and, more importantly, with the `array` data itself: if one loop's `j` is the same as another loop's `j + 1`, then the attempt to swap the elements will cause a data race (access collision).

*To summarize: parallelization of a bubble sort is not practical unless you create far more complex code. For an example, [see here](https://www.cs.iusb.edu/%7Edanav/teach/b424/b424_15_bubblesort.html).*

Comment: Where @AdrianMole has *There* may *also be a similar problem* I'd write *There* is *also a similar problem*.  That's not an error you can expect the compiler to fix.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark OK, there are deeper issues involved here. See latest edit (though maybe not the answer the OP is looking for).

Comment: The OpenMP runtime splits the set of iterations into `n` chunks, not the data structures, so you are right to suspect that neighbouring threads may well update `array[j]` and `array[j+1]` without coordination.  It certainly is a *data race*.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I understand you. Could you suggest some examples where it would be useful to study the working time with and without OpenMP? For example, other types of sorting. Thanks.

Comment: @prostargamer I'll have a dig around, to see what I can come up with.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: @prostargamer Changing your question after an answer has been posted is sometimes frowned upon by Stack Overflow folks (I'm personally not that bothered in this case, but maybe you should, technically, rollback your edit and post a new question.) See: [Moving Goalposts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252113/10871073).

Comment: @AdrianMole, I understand you.
Tell me, what is the problem now? Why can't I generate random numbers in parallel?

Comment: @prostargamer Although you may *think* your question is still the same, the causes of the problems are **very** different. Do the roll-back and ask a new question. You will likely get quick (and good) answers to a new question.

Comment: Okay, I'll do this.